# Unable to access Google Compute VM

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I am unable to access Google VM using Terminal on Mac and browser SSH provided by Google.

On Terminal, it gives me error (when i run sudo gcloud compute ssh instance-name):
**Permission denied (publickey)**

When i try browser SSH, it says:
**Could not connect, retrying..**

What i have tried till now:

1. Removed all SSH keys of the project from the Cloud console.
2. Removed SSH key from my system.
3. Used gcloud init
4. Ran **sudo gcloud compute ssh instance-name** and it created a new SSH Key and updated the key to the project key

But it is still giving the same errors.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to VM from your Windows machine, your windows username must be contains just English charackters. I've had such a problem than I change my windows profile, It was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method that has worked for me:

### Create the SSH Key

In the terminal type `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/{filename} -C {username}`

Upload the Public Key to your VM

1. In the terminal type `cat ~/.ssh/{filename}.pub`
2. Copy the results to the clipboard
3. Back in Google Cloud's Console: Click on your instance name
4. Click 'Edit'
5. Scroll down to 'SSH'
6. Where it says "enter entire key data: Paste
7. Save

### Connect via the Terminal

Type in `ssh -i ~/.ssh/{filename}.ppk {username}@{ip-address}`